# Parallel algorithm to use in place of PORTA?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

We currently use PORTA software to find the list of facet-defining inequalities (FDI) for polytopes that we work with.  For certain polytopes, PORTA works fine.  But because it is a serial algorithm (uses Fourier-Motzkin) we sometimes encounter cases where the analysis simply takes too long and we have to force the program to stop.  We are wondering if there exists a parallel algorithm that would allow us to complete these computations faster? Ideally we would prefer to have exact solutions like PORTA gives; but in lieu of such software programs we would be open to trying a method that may not yield exact results.  (And if it matters:  our input coordinates are almost always discrete, either 0 or 1.)

Comment: There is a parallel version of fourier motzkin: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0024686?LI=true

Comment: Thanks Paul--now we just need to find someone to help us write the program!